# Creating waypoint coordinates on a grid within an area

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, area, grids-graticules

Do you know which GIS software or online tool supports returning GPS coordinates on a grid within an area? Kinda like waypoints for drone photographing 90 degrees looking down of an area for 3d modelling.

[image]